# unable to end the mysql connection using the promise

Tags: node.js, promise, jasmine, mysql2

Followings are my piece of code, please have a look into it.

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var connection;

mysql.createConnection({host:'Ip', user:'qa', password: '******'}).then(function(conn){
connection = conn;
return connection.query(firstInput);
})
.then(function(rows){
console.log(rows);
})

.then(function(){
console.log("End of DB Con.");
return connection.end();

})
.catch(function(error){
//logs out the error
console.log(error);
});
```

Once I try to execute the code for different Jasmine tests all works Ok as it's fetch the records from DB but when it comes to executing the last jasmine test it retain the records from second last query that was executed in second last test. This is the exact problem!

=========================================================================
Added more detail related to this problem as:

Followings my piece of code of fetching the records from DB:

1) First function related to DB connection and Query:

```
function dbMySqlInteraction (query, callback) {
Promise = require('bluebird');
var mysql = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql'));
var connection = mysql.createConnection({host:'ip', user:'qa', 
password:'*********'});

connection.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
callback(results);
});
```

2) Below mentioned code will print the records fetched from db and then PHPSESSID comparison:

```
dbMySqlInteraction(query, function(cBT){

var lastRow = cBT[cBT.length-1];

////////////////// Print Stats ////////////////////////////////
//console.log(lastRow.stats_datetime);
console.log('Stats recorded/fetched from DB as: ');
allure.createStep('Stats recorded/fetched from DB as: ', function(){

for (var key in lastRow) {
if (lastRow.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
allure.createStep(key +': ' + lastRow[key], function(){})();
console.log(key +': ' + lastRow[key]);
}
}
})();

browser.sleep(2000);
////////////////// PHPSESSID Comparison ///////////////////////////////
browser.manage().getCookie("PHPSESSID").then(function(cookies) {
console.log('Got Browser PHPSESSID As: ', cookies.value);
allure.createStep('Got Browser PHPSESSID As: ' + cookies.value, function(
{})();

var dBSessionID = lastRow.session_id;

console.log("DB Session ID: " + dBSessionID);
allure.createStep("DB Session ID: " + dBSessionID, function(){})();

console.log('Stats recorded time: ' + lastRow.stats_datetime);
allure.createStep('Stats recorded time: ' + lastRow.stats_datetime, 
function(){})();

expect(cookies.value).toEqual(dBSessionID);
});
});
//connection.end();
browser.sleep(2000);
```

I need to execute all above mentioned code as a part of each jasmine test but sometime "dBSessionID" fetch from earlier Jasmine test will retain itself in coming jasmine test and according to assertion it will be marked as failed due to NOT equal to PHPSESSID of browser.

Comment: You didn't post any jasmine tests nor your queries?

Comment: Hi @Bergi My query relevant code is mentioned above in main thread but following is my actual problem while in jasmine test: I have to applied the ASSERTION in jasmine tests based on the followings factors:

1) Got Browser based PHPSESSID by using Protractor-Jasmine
2) Got the PHPSESSID stored in DB by using mysql2 as well as promise-mysql
And I have compared for all test, except the last one where it retain PHPSESSID fetch form second last test. That's why my jasmine tests gets failed.

Comment: seems like that sort of detail should be in the question itself, not a comment

Comment: if you write code that looks like that, no indentation, then no wonder you are having problems debugging it for yourself